# Setting Path of UIImage

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, sprite

I would like to know how to set the path (into folders) of a UIImage when I'm doing something like this:

[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sprites/Macbeth/Climbing/1.png"];

I want to to have it use the image entitled "1.png" in the folder Sprite, in that folder in Macbeth and in that folder Climbing. I want to be able to do that with one line of code since I have a lot of UIImages like that for sprite animations (all in arrays). Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS does not maintain the folder system you have. So this isn't possible. You would pull your image simply using this line of code.

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
```

Instead of trying to nest folders try putting that into the file name like macbeth-climbing-1.png if you need to classify multiple 1.png's

Comment: Ok, thanks! That'll be a lot of editing, but hopefully it's be worth it!

Comment: Try using Automator to rename all your images using the folder names :) Should be breeze then.

Comment: Haha, I didn't see this comment until I finished :X. I'll do that next time though!

Answer (score 1):

Write a method or function that does the following:

1. Call `[NSBundle mainBundle]` to get your application bundle
2. Call `-[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:]` to get the path to the image
3. Call `+[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` with that path